# variable not changing until a button is pressed

Tags: java, android

I have a sharedPreference field 'mute' if its true is skips the sound  on buttons. I have a checkbox to turn the sharedPrefernce field 'true' or 'false, However, when the checkbox it checked / unchecked, the effect doesn't happen until a button is pressed, ie its ticked true (to mute), the next button makes a noise, then it stopps.

this is my code for the onclickListener

```
CheckBox mute = findViewById(R.id.mute);
mute.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked){
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("taxini", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("mute", "true");
            editor.apply();
            MUTE.equals("true");
        }else {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("taxini", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("mute", "false");
            editor.apply();
            MUTE.equals("false");
        }

    }
}
```

why does it not have immediate effect? on each activity I have the MUTE variable loaded with the sharedPref. its just the very first button.
thanks.

Comment: MUTE.equals("true/false") are dead code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the method `onCheckedChanged()` is invoked both times? (Both for "mute" and "unmute"?).

You could pop `System.out.println("test")` in there and see.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a normal listener as follow :

```
mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        CheckBox chk=(CheckBox)view;
        if(chk.isChecked())
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

Also you can use `isChecked()` method in your listener :

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
    if(buttonView.isChecked()) {
        // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've used your code above, i'm still getting the issue. I think I am going to start again with it, I'm new to android and this is a learning curve. I've used Soundpool and Audio Manager. With some more research, it seems I should have used the MediaPlayer instead.